# Excel dynamic Ranking

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to rank a series basis 3 conditions. But unable to do so.

I am using the below formula

```
{=RANK.EQ(G4,INDEX((($G4:$G219)*($D4:$D219=$D4)*($F4:$F219=$F4)*1),,1),0)}
```

but its not working. I am attaching the link to my excel file. Could someone guide me how to achieve it.

[Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgRb-l7PkcD8hVHB9kmh1X1VwrYZ)

Comment: Perhaps the way question is posted is not correct or reflects that i have not put in enough efforts. But Could someone just point me as to why the **INDEX((($G4:$G219)*($D4:$D219=$D4)*($F4:$F219=$F4)*1),,1)** is showing array when doing F9 but not returning it in Rank formula.

Comment: But column G contains TEXT values ("SP1"), and you can't 'multiply' text values by Booleans, hence ($G4:$G219)*($D4:$D219=$D4)*($F4:$F219=$F4) will result in errors where column G contains "SP1".